# Running Ubuntu from a USB Stick - Can't Locate any Files in Windows partition

Tags: live-usb

I just tried running Ubuntu from a USB Stick and I can't locate any files created under XP - documents, photos, etc.  Can't even find the `C:` drive.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Ubuntu did you start? I assume you are referring to 12.04.

At first, look at the left for an icon named "Home folder". Click it and you will see a window similar to Windows Explorer, like in this screenshot.

[image]

Then look at the devices and search for your Windows drive. It will not be called "C" but it has the same label (e.g. "Windows").

Comment: Found "Devices", but the only folder in there was "Casper-rw" which I could not access.  Any thoughts?  Yes, it is version 12.04.

Comment: What is the label of your hard drive in Windows? Could you check in Windows Explorer with "right click / Properties"? I want to ensure that "Casper-rw" is not your hard drive. If it is not, there is the possibility that Ubuntu did not detect your hard drive correctly.

Comment: Simply says "Drive C".  And in the upper box where a name can be entered, it says "System".

Comment: Ah, okay, capser-rw seems to be the name of the mounted live system. What type of hard disk do you have installed? Is it a common IDE/SATA drive?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think so.  Rel. new laptop.  NTFS file system.

Comment: Do you see your drive when following these instructions? https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/disk-partitions.html

Comment: That showed a bunch more - but they all look like system files like .cache, .config- no Windows files.

Comment: Update:  reading from an older post, it looks like when booting from a USB, my BIOS does not recognize that there is a hard-drive.  That would explain it.  If Ubunto is installed along-side of Windows, can it later be deleted?

Comment: Yes, you can simply delete the Ubuntu partition, but be sure to reinstall the original boot loader as described in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on). If you need help with this, please open another question.

Comment: You are welcome. I would appreciate if you mark the answer as "correct" or "helpful".